# Rails: Refresh browser automatically when view (and related) files change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation, view

A lot of my work (in Rails) actually centers around the views, images, SASS/CSS and Coffescript/Javascript files and I'd love to have a solution that refreshes the browser, whenever I make a change to any of this type of files. A little like autotest or watchr but for 'design' tasks.

I've looked at watchr and fs-event, which seem to provide related functionality and look around the web, but I couldn't find any ready solution yet. Did I miss something? Hard to believe that this wouldn't have been done yet — the tools clearly exist.

Assuming that a tool like this really doesn't exist, I'd like to have crack at writing my own solution. So if you have some advice on what to consider, where to have a look at interesting projects etc. — I'd appreciate that as well.

**Update**
An example workflow would look like this:

1. Start "watcher application" in terminal
2. Rails server starts if it's not running
3. Browser window opens automagically pointing to rails server
4. I go and change a change some HTML in a view
5. The browser refreshes automatically
6. I update some CSS
7. The browser refreshes automatically
8. I add a new JS file
9. The browser refreshes automatically
10. …

Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your description I would think that [LiveReload](https://github.com/mockko/livereload) would do the trick for you.

You'll need to change the `.livereload` file to only reload the browser on specific file change but it's all covered in the readme (scroll to the configuration section)

There's also [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/) that can do pretty much the same stuff but I've never used it.

Comment: Livereload looks pretty good! Do you happen to know if there's a way that I could use this with Firefox?

Comment: XRefresh seems to be just what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try [Guard::Livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload). It will automatically reload your browser when 'view' files are modified.

For more information (and a demo) see: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/264-guard

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this project?

https://github.com/logankoester/autorefresh

Comment: This look great as well! Gotta read a little, but this might be just what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, this is sweet — thanks! Although I'm not a too big fan of having to insert code into my project just to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I've found something I think is even better than any of these options.  With [Live.js](http://livejs.com/) you don't even need to modify your project, you can just click the bookmarklet and it will automatically update when something changes.

The only downside is that you will get a lot of HEAD requests in your server log, but since I use this when doing style edits that doesn't really bother me.  I'd much rather have that then have to modify my project just for a development tool.

Comment: Looks like an interesting option. However, with Rails 4 and SSE I’m expecting a Rails–only version as gem to pop up almost instantly.

Answer (score 1):

For **Rails 6 or 7** running with Hotwire (default) you can use the [hotwire-livereload gem](https://github.com/kirillplatonov/hotwire-livereload).  It watches assets and views and uses ActionCable (websockets) to trigger a refresh over turbo.

Note that #3 (opening a web browser) in your example workflow won't be covered.